# Мужской-женский род в новообразовании

Tags: фразеология, морфология, род

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться! 
Было создано словосочетание "Мнемосиновы исчисления". Но, если вспомнить, что Мнемосина - это женщина, подобная форма "Мнемосиновы" кажется ошибочной. Но "Мнемосинины исчисления" звучат и читаются слишком коряво и не "по-научному". Можено ли оставить первый вариант? Или нужно обязательно применять второй?

Comment: Если можно поменять слова местами: «исчисления Мнемосины» звучит естественнее. Второй вариант — правильный, но читается плохо.

Comment: "Исчисления Мнемосины" - подразумевают присутствие самой Мнемосины, её действия в каждом из этих вычислений. Но это просто научный термин, относящийся к самой титаниде очень опосредовано.

Comment: И ещё одно - "закон Бойля-Мариотта" и "Архимедовы штаны". "МИ" - это именно "Архимедовы штаны"! Разговорный термин.

Comment: Если быть точным, то правильно - **пифагоровы штаны**. Есть и другие _сокровища геометрии,_  с ними (штанами) связанные: пифагоровы треугольники и пифагоровы тройки.

Comment: Ой! Позор на мои....!!! Писал второпях, а башка была занята Архимедом. :((( Но смысл понятен, даже несмотря на мою ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

1) **О суффиксах ОВ/ЕВ и ИН**

Сфера распространения притяжательных прилагательных на ОВ/ЕВ и ИН, образованных  от нарицательных существительных,  – это **разговорная речь и художественная литература.** Семантика узкая, они указывают н**а индивидуальную принадлежность.** В современном литературном языке  заменяются сущ. в Р.п.: тётино письмо – письмо тёти, дедово ружье – ружьё деда.

Использование этих суффиксов возможно в притяжательных прилагательных, образованные **от имен**: Машины куклы, Иваново детство.

**Но устарели формы на ОВ/ЕВ образованные от фамилий**: вместо Марксов «Капитал», Гегелева «Логика», Далев «Словарь» используются сочетания с родительным падежом существительного – «Капитал» Маркса, «Логика» Гегеля, «Словарь» Даля. [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm#%D0%B7_04)

В то же время в речи сохраняются **устойчивые выражения с этими суффиксами в нарицательном значении**: ахиллесова пята, крокодиловы слёзы, ариаднина нить, сизифов труд.

2) **Мнемосиновы исчисления**

Ближайший аналог – **ариаднина нить.** Это нарицательное сочетание (без значения индивидуальной принадлежности) пишется со строчной буквы, является устойчивым сочетанием, содержит суффикс ИН. Этот суффикс  характерен для основ на А/Я (это может быть ж. и м. род).

Надо сказать, что не от всякой основы можно образовать удобную для произношения притяжательную форму, например, мы скажем: **дочери Мнемосины, но не Мнемосинины дочери.**

3) **И вывод:** прописать данное новообразование в языке весьма сложно и по-научному никак не получится.

**Чисто разговорный вариант** – это "мнемозиновы исчисления". Сочетание воспринимается как термин (сравнить: адамово яблоко, антонов огонь, кесарево сечение), а суффикс ОВ, а не ИН не так важен, так как имя богини памяти достаточно узнаваемо.

Comment: _Но устарели формы на ОВ/ЕВ образованные от фамилий_ Несть им числа в математике.

Comment: А есть какой-либо пример притяжательного прилагательного с суффиксом ОВ, образованного от существительного женского рода?

Comment: @default locale См. комментарий в моём ответе. Даже лучше — от имени другой богини.

Comment: "Ариадна" не катит. У нее нет в конце "-ина" из-за чего все сомнения. Предлагаю "Прозерпина" (см. мой ответ).

Comment: Именно так  должно быть - это наукообразный термин, астрофизического процесса, закона, который не имеет теоретического обоснования. Только практическое применение. Я его пишу с больших букв именно потому, что применение этого закона, для большинства происходит за гранью разумного. Что-то вроде имени Бога.

Answer (score 1):

> Было создано словосочетание "Мнемосиновы исчисления". Но...

Не вижу особых проблем в таком словообразовании. Термин напоминает математический (был бы полезен контекст употребления, чтобы не было сомнений в корректности), где подобное словообразование вполне принято. Например: нётерово кольцо, нётеров модуль, нётерово пространство, нётерова индукция и т.п. — термины, которые названы в честь Эмми Нётер.

Дополнение.
Приведу ещё в качестве косвенного примера с ОВ название от богини женского рода: семейство афродитовых.

Comment: Для такой основы (на согласный) суффикс ОВ формально подходит, если речь идет именно о суффиксе. Автора смущал суффикс ИН, а он связан с основой на А/Я, а не с женскими родом.

Comment: @Jasmin Наверное, Вы правы. Но мне почему-то и "мнемосиновы" слух не режет.

Comment: @Jasmin Пример для основы на гласный: математик Вольтерра и вольтерровы уравнения. Просто с женщинами примеры сложнее находить — в их честь не так много терминов названо.

Comment: «Мнемосиновы» это принадлежащие некоему Мнемосину, как «диофантовы уравнения», «дамоклов меч» и т.п. От женского имени такое прилагательное получить нельзя: это все равно что писать «анютовы глазки» или «венерова мухоловка». Сравните : «Федорино горе» и «Федорово горе».

Comment: @default locale Судя по Вашей логике, семейство афродитовых названо в честь какого-то Афродита, а не по имени богини Афродиты.

Comment: @grizzly Хороший пример, спасибо! Почему-то суффикс -ОВ- казался (и до сих пор кажется) исключительно мужским. Не разобрался в ситуации, виноват. Приношу свои извинения.

Comment: @grizzly  *Но мне почему-то и "мнемосиновы" слух не режет* - Мнемосина не на слуху. Если не знать, что єто богиня, а полагать, что єто какая-нибудь бабочка, а лучше - растение,, было бы относительно нормально. Это уже не притяжательное прилагательное в чистом виде, а сокращение для "...образные". Тоже и с Волтеррой, имхо. Никто не знает, что там "-а"  на конце, а кто знает, не думает, что это флексия. Известный пример - с "Дантом" (который не презирал сонета). Окончание в разговорной речи отбрасывается  и Вольтерра стаеовится "Вольтерром".  Вот "афродитовые" меня больше зацепили.

Comment: Видимо, они тоже -образные - не от Афодиты напрямую, а от червей "афродиты", с которыми греческая Афродита поделилась именем. И вот их-то, червей, считать женщинами нет никакого смысла. По аналогичным мотивам биологи вообще склонны к единому словообразовательному суффиксу - ов/ев..*Венерин башмачок* - это народное название, не переводное.

Comment: Насчёт контекста - нет проблем: Уранникова постоянно величали по-разному — то доктором, то академиком, то профессором, а то и «профессором Академии». В одних этих званиях разобраться – уже наука не для средних умов!
В любом случае, без его Мнемосиновых Исчислений, путь от звёздной системы Харея, откуда прибыл «Кархародон», до той точки космоса в гигантском войде Хоффмана, где крутилась Станция, занял бы долгие десятилетия!
Поэтому, «профессор-доктор-академик» Уранников числился во всём мире чем-то вроде мага и волшебника, личностью уникальной, и почитаемой всеми разумными существами.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, образование "мнемосинов" от "Мнемосина" невозможно ни в каком варианте. 
Ни как притяжательное прилагательное, ни в качестве фамилии (грамматика этих форм общая).

Здесь дело даже не в женском роде, а в том, что это существительное первого склонения (школьного, на -а/-я): папин, машин (от Маша), ванин (от Ваня), подружкин, воеводин... Аналогично и для третьего склонения: мышин.

Исключения единичны, связаны с колебанием рода в третьем склонении (конев-конин) или в фамилиях с неоднозначно выделяемой основой (Путин - не от "путь" скорее всего), а также с образованиями от множественного числа - зубкин об "зубки".

Ошибки при образовании таких форм прилагательных связаны, вероятно, с постепенным вытеснением этих форм родительным падежом: "Машина книга" вместо "книга Маши". Но устаревшими признать никак не могу.

> "Мнемосинины исчисления" звучат и читаются слишком коряво...

У Чуковского есть "Федорино горе". Чем Феодора лучше Мнемосины?
Тут, видимо, такая штука, что окончание -ин похоже на русский суффикс, а таких суффиксов больше одного быть не может у русских слов. Но для иностранных имен, где первое вхождение совсем не суффикс, - запросто.

Как ни тоскуем, все уйдем
Мы в **Прозерпинин** дом
И асфоделевым венком
Венчаться будем в нем.
(Георгий Шенгели, "Айсигена")

Ну и всевозможные **балеринин, катеринин, Маринин** никаких сомнений не вызывающие.

Увидел в комментариях пример с "афродитовыми". Он меня немножко поколебал, но скорее всего это закрепившийся казус перевода. В биологии принято придерживаться определенной систематики даже в образовании таких форм. Но пример любопытный.